# Heroku Postgres Attached as HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Recently I have created a new Heroku application based on old Heroku application. In my application, I am using Heroku Postgres as a datastores. I am using `Heroku Postgres` with `Standard 0` plan. I just realised that both applications have attached a database in a different manner.

the old application(Postgres version 9.6.17) says **Attached as HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT**
The new application(Postgres version 12.2) says **Attached as DATABASE**

Also, one of application has **Attached as HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN**

In my old application, I have **HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL** in **Config Vars** but not in a new application.

Just curious what is the difference between them? or Do they have any significant changes or just version changes? I have tried to find differences but not found proper resources for understanding.

Comment: I think the difference here is really just how the attachments map to the actual ENV vars inside the Heroku App. Rails uses `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` to actually connect to the database and does not really care about your Heroku setup. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: @max I don't think it's just a map vars difference.